# не отображаются углы CardView после клика на элементе

Tags: android, cardview

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить проблему с закруглёнными углами CardView. При клике на CardView устанавливаю анимацию изменения цвета вот таким образом:

```
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, startColor)),
                new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, endColor))};
TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
card.setBackground(trans);
trans.startTransition(2000);
```

Код разметки для CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/error_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:onClick="onClickCard"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorError"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:contentPadding="4dp"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/warning_card">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/error_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/error_description"
                card_view:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/error_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/error_string"
                android:textColor="@color/cardTextColor"
                android:textSize="40sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Анимация срабатывает, но при первом же клике закруглённые углы ищезают и cardView отображается как обычный прямоугольник. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: у вас края закруглены через drawable, который в начальном стейте background у карточки стоит, а вы его перезатираете новым drawable, скорее всего

Comment: края закруглены с помощью свойства app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" в разметке

Comment: хм, попробуйте сперва без анимации, затем setbackgroundcolor, так работает?

Comment: да, пока я не использую этот код, который представлен в вопросе, все работает. Когда подключаю анимацию и кликаю на элементе, углы ищезают.

Comment: приведите код cardview разметки

Comment: хм, вроде выглядит нормально

Comment: может обычный баг?

Comment: ну я видимо не до конца понимаю, как работают карточки, поэтому не могу подсказать, в чём именно проблема, очевидно, что нарушается объект при смене drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте пойти другим путём:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(card, "cardBackgroundColor", new int[] { startColor, endColor});
animator.setDuration(2000);
animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
animator.start();
```